# How can i make buffer protection actually work?

Tags: c

I have to make the `name` struct to be just 5 characters of type `char`.
This means that if i pass in an argument for a name that is more than 5 characters, there should be no output.
But when i pass in a command line argument of a name with 9 characters, i still get an output. Here is my source code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

struct _data {                          
   char name[5];
   long number;
}; 


int SCAN(FILE *(*stream)) {         
int counter = 0;
size_t chrCount;
char *text;
   // Open the file and make sure it was opened.
   if ((*stream = fopen("file.data", "r")) == NULL) {
      printf("ERROR - file could not be opened.\n");
      exit(0);
   }
   // Use getline to read in a full line of data/text.
   while (1) {
      text = NULL;
      getline(&text, &chrCount, *stream);   
      free(text);
      if (feof(*stream)) break;
      counter++;
   }
   return counter;
}


struct _data *LOAD(FILE *stream, int counter) 
{   
    int i;
    size_t chrCount;
    char *text, *phone, *name;
    struct _data *BlackBox;
    // Allocate memory for array of struct.
    if ((BlackBox = (struct _data*)calloc(counter, sizeof(struct _data))) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR - Could not allocate memory.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    rewind(stream);
    // Use getline to read in ALL of the data/text.
    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        text  = NULL;
        getline(&text, &chrCount, stream);
        name  = strtok(text, " ");      
        phone = strtok(NULL, "\n");     
        // Allocate memory for name part of struct.
        strncpy(BlackBox[i].name, name, 5);     
        //BlackBox[i].name[4] = '\0';
        BlackBox[i].number = atol(phone);   
        free(text);
    }
    fclose(stream);
    return BlackBox;                // Return pointer to dynamic array.
}


void SEARCH(struct _data *BlackBox, char *name, int counter) {
int i;
int found = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
       if (!strncmp(name, BlackBox[i].name, 5)) {
          printf("************************************************ \n");
            printf("[%s] was found at the %d entry.\n",name, i);
            printf("************************************************* \n");
          found = 1;
          break;
       }
   } 
   if (found == 0) {
    printf("*******************************************\n");
    printf("The name was NOT found.\n");
    printf("*******************************************\n");
   }

}


void FREE(struct _data *BlackBox, int counter) {
int i;
   for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
       //free(BlackBox[i].name);
   } 
   free(BlackBox);
   BlackBox = NULL;
}

/*****************************************************/
/* Main                                              */
/*****************************************************/
int main(int argv, char **argc) {
int size;
FILE *data;
struct _data *BlackBox;
    if (argv == 1) {
       printf("*******************************************\n");
       printf("* You must include a name to search for.  *\n");
       printf("*******************************************\n");
    }
    if (argv == 2) {
       size = SCAN(&data);
       BlackBox = LOAD(data, size);
       SEARCH(BlackBox, argc[1], size);
       FREE(BlackBox, size);
   }
   return 1;
}
```

And here is my data file that i use for testing

```
ronnette 7774013
jon 7774014
tommyy 7774015
won won 7774016
```

I am required to use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` and `strncmp` instead of `strcmp`.
when i pass the name ronnette into the command line, i get the output location in the file. But based on my understanding of buffers, since the name ronnette has more than 5 characters, it is not supposed to run.
Please how can i fix the code to actually do the buffer protection?

Comment: Your code looks like it is truncating too-long names to 4 characters.  It doesn't look like it is rejecting them.

Comment: Remember that C strings are null-terminated character arrays. To have a five character name, you need a six char array.

Comment: @SteveSummit i thought that modification will ensure that the last memory ends up being `'\0'` which indicates the end of the string. Have any ideas how i can actually make it to reject any names over 5 characters?

Comment: Right.  `strncpy` copies at most 5 characters (leaving a possibly-malformed, non-null-terminated string), and then you explicitly set the last byte to `\0`, so now you've definitely got a valid string of length at most 4.

Comment: @Chris i see. but i am allowed only that particular given struct. so that i why i included this `BlackBox[i].name[4] = '\0';` to account for that. any other way to do it excluding this line?

Comment: When you call `strncmp(name, BlackBox[i].name, 4)`, you're comparing just the first four characters.  So `"ronnette"` counts as a match for `"ronn"`.  You could additionally check that `strlen(name)` is less than or equal to 4.

Comment: @SteveSummit ok, with that being the case, why then or how can i make sure it only reads in a name of at most 5 char? thanks

Comment: Your teacher gave you a horrible assignment, though.  `strncpy` and `strncmp` are confusing functions, that most modern programmers don't use and don't recommend using.  You're engaged in a frustrating task to learn something that doesn't work well and isn't even useful.

Comment: You *did* make it read a name of at most 4 characters.  So it didn't read `ronnette`, it just read `ronn`.  And if you had asked for `ronn` on the command line, it would have found `ronn`.  And if you ask for `ronnette` on the command line, it will find `ronn`.  And if you ask for `ronnxxyyzz` on the command line, it will find `ronn`.  Me, I would call this "working" (within the limits of this badly-desifned problem), and move on.  What did your instructor say was supposed to happen?

Comment: If you don't want `ronnette` to find `ronn`, you can't use `strncmp` like that.  You either need to use `strcmp`, or use `strncmp` plus a separate test on the string length.

Comment: @SteveSummit ok, let me edit the question and take out anything with 4 in it. Because we are only allowed the name[5] struct. the main challenge is getting it to seg fault when char name>5 as the buffer is supposed to do

Comment: Wait, what, you *want* it to segfault?

Comment: @SteveSummit ok . used just strcmp and it does work. but instead of a seg fault message, it just says the name was not found; even though its in the data file. ran ronnette and jonnyy

Comment: @SteveSummit i thought it has to seg fault when i input a name larger than the accepted char size right? for buffer overflows

Comment: Here are three questions you need to answer.  Once you have answered them, someone else may be able to help you.  Me, I'm out of time here.

Comment: Question 1.  Do you want to store names in your database of length at most 4, or of length at most 5?  More precisely, do you want to store names of length at most 4 that are always properly null-terminated strings, or do you want to play with names of length at most 5 that are not-necessarily-null-terminated non-strings?

Comment: Question 2: If the input file contains a name that's too long, do you want to (a)  store a record with a truncated version of the name, (b) reject that record (not store it in your database at all) or (c) reject the entire input file?

Comment: Question 3: When searching for a name in the database, and if the name that you're searching for is too long, meaning that it can't possibly be found in the database, do you want it to (1) say "not found", (2) possibly match in the first 4 or 5 characters, or (3) do something undefined, like crashing with a segmentation fault?  (As for #3, I don't know why you would want it to do that, and based on the code you have so far, I honestly don't know how you would do that.)

Comment: @SteveSummit yes, a name of length at most 5 characters and if the command line takes in a name larger than five char, even if the larger name is in the data file, it should throw out an error message like "name too long" i.e reject the record.

Comment: C does not do any checking for buffer overflow. None. If you overflow a buffer, any random thing could happen. That's why it's called "Undefined Behaviour" and not, for example, "mandatory segfault". (Actually, many operating systems do not use the phrase *segfault* at all.) So if you want your program to halt if some constraint is violated, ***you*** have to do the check and ***you*** have to terminate the program (for example, by calling `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`. Big agree with Steve about this assignment and the use of `strncpy` and `strncmp`, which are designed for a specific use case.

Comment: @jtmopao - The statement _if the command line takes in a name larger than five char, … it should throw out an error message like "name too long" i.e reject the record_ is nonsensical - a command line argument is not a record.